# Vue v-model and proxy first set is not called

Tags: javascript, vue.js, proxy

Currently I am working on a Vue project where I want to have a model class that stores all its initial data in two properties: `original` and `attributes`. However I am having difficulties with binding properties to an input via `v-model`.

Lets say I have the following class:

```
class Model
{
    constructor () {
        return new Proxy(this, {
            get: (target, property, receiver) => {
                console.log('get');
                return target[property];
            },

            set: (target, property, value, receiver) => {
                console.log('set');
                target[property] = value + 123;
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This class will log `get` when getting a property and `set` when setting a property. Also while setting it will add `123` at the end of the value. The following will be executed:

```
let model = new Model();

model.name = 'test'; // Logs: 'set'

console.log(model.name); // Logs: 'get' and 'test123'
```

This works as expected.

The problems start when I bind these properties to an input via `v-model`. The following happens:

Actions are executed on:

```
<input v-model="model.name" />
...
data () {
    return {
        model: new Model
    };
}
```

On the first change the property `name` will be added to the `model` object. No log at all. No added `123` at the end of the value. The model value has changed to `{ model: 't' }`.

Second change it will log `set` and it will add `123`. The model value has changed to `{ model: 'te123' }`.

Logging the arguments of of the `set` call during the second change:
`Model {__ob__: Observer}, "name", "te", Proxy {__ob__: Observer}`

Anyone had this problem before or knows what is going on here?

**After answer of @sphinx**

Thank you for your answer! It works!

To make things more complicated I want to have the properties that are in a certain `fillable` array to be set in a property called `attributes`. However the same behaviour returns.

```js
class Model
{
    constructor () {
        this.attributes = {};
        this.fillable = ['name'];

        return new Proxy(this, {
            get: (target, property, receiver) => {
                console.log('get', property);

                if (target.fillable.indexOf(property) > -1) { // Check if in fillable
                    if (!(property in  target.attributes)) {
                        Vue.set(target.attributes, property, null);
                    }

                    return target.attributes[property];
                }

                return target[property];
            },
            set: (target, property, value, receiver) => {
                console.log('set', property, value);

                if (target.fillable.indexOf(property) > -1) {
                    Vue.set(target.attributes, property, value + 123);
                } else {
                    target[property] = value
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      test: new Model
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span>{{test.name}}</span>
    <input v-model="test.name" type="text">
</div>
```

During the first change the `name` property is set directly on the `model` object. But the `set` method is not called.

During the second change the `name` property is changing and the `set` method is called.

Any suggestions on why this happens?

Comment: Why you don't instantiate the Model correctly: new Model() ?

Comment: @MátéWiszt there are no arguments in my constructor, so it is not needed.

Comment: In Vue's current implementation, it attaches getters and setters to each own property of the object it is observing. I don't think `Proxy` objects are supported by Vue.

Answer (score 2):

In your exammple, the getter will create one property, but it is not reactivity (check [Vue Guide: Reactivity In Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#ad)).

So Vue can't **track the changes**.

The solution is easy as above guide introduces, uses `Vue.set` or `vm.$set` to make sure your object is reactivity.

Like below demo:

```js
class Model
{
    constructor () {
        return new Proxy(this, {
            get: (target, property, receiver) => {
                console.log('get', property);
                if(!(property in target)) Vue.set(target, property, null)
                return target[property]
            },
            set: (target, property, value, receiver) => {
                console.log('set', property, value);
                Vue.set(target, property, value + 123)
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      test: new Model
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span>{{test.name}}</span>
    <input v-model="test.name" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works! However I want to add the properties to another property inside the `Model`. I have updated my answer with some more info. Would you like to have a look?

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen what about always use `Vue.set(target.attributes, property, null)` (put it outside `if(fillable){}` block)